# spacing between videos inside a div not getting applied

Tags: html, css

I have a main div called shelf2 with a height of auto. It has 2 divs inside of it. One is a list of divs with the same class name and height and separated by a 2vw row gap. Beside it is a container named rightAdCon with 3 random videos inside it. Now the problem i have is in the class rightAdCon. I set the 3 videos inside of that div to have spacing/ row-gap of 0vw but it's not getting applied to it. The videos always have spacing between them even with row-gap specified to 0vw. To debug i replicated the same code of class rightAdCon under the main div (shelf2) and gave it a new class name (rightAdCon2). Now on this div the row gap i specified works and the spacing between the videos will get removed. This shows that there is something inside the shelf2 container interfering with the spacing I specified but I cant figure out what. How can I make the spacing between the videos in the class rightAdCon to 0vw just how it is in the replica under it (rightAdCon2). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Maybe because I used static measurement on the `rightAdCon` height. I set it to `100%` changing that to a relative measurement like height `90em` is something I thought of but didn't work but I got a feeling its something related to that.

```js
// just code to make the rightadcon2 positioned under shelf2 js code has noting to do with the question

$('.rightAdCon2').css('top', $('.shelf2').offset().top + $('.shelf2').height() + 20)
```

```css
.shelf2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

.shelf2 .otherItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 2vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: purple;
}

.shelf2 .otherItems .beat3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7em;
  background-color: blue;
}

.shelf2 .rightAdCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  /*not getting applied*/
  row-gap: 0vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 1%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.shelf2 .rightAdCon .adCon {
  height: 25%;
}

.shelf2 .rightAdCon .adCon video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightAdCon2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  /* this is getting applied*/
  row-gap: 0vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 1%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.rightAdCon2 .adCon {
  height: 25%;
}

.rightAdCon2 .adCon video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shelf2">
  <div class="otherItems">
    <div class="beat3">
    </div>
    <div class="beat3">
    </div>
    <div class="beat3">
    </div>
    <div class="beat3">
    </div>
    <div class="beat3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightAdCon">
    <div class="adCon">
      <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/401025531.sd.mp4?s=9b1bf00feea177c8d0d1d465b304a3d9c1ae0eee&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
    <div class="adCon">
      <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/479498538.sd.mp4?s=a1436f498fa9be8a887062a98de2ec1eddaa6167&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
    <div class="adCon">
      <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/394555897.sd.mp4?s=8f069cc18f74ecc7cad689223f65cf49990711f5&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rightAdCon2">
  <div class="adCon">
    <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/401025531.sd.mp4?s=9b1bf00feea177c8d0d1d465b304a3d9c1ae0eee&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="adCon">
    <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/479498538.sd.mp4?s=a1436f498fa9be8a887062a98de2ec1eddaa6167&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="adCon">
    <video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/394555897.sd.mp4?s=8f069cc18f74ecc7cad689223f65cf49990711f5&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you're using viewport width (vw) as your units everywhere?

I think in this situation it would make more sense to set `row-gap: none;` or `row-gap: 0;` in this scenario. `vw` should only be used when you need a unit relative to the screen width, which in this case, you don't.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I coded this question on SO in a hurry so I used ```vw``` there by mistake but either way issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

always have videos inside a div, give the videos properties of `object-fit: contain or cover` and only manipulate the spaces between/sizes of the divs

PS: to keep the divs always the same sizes give them the property of `aspect-ratio: 16/9 or 1/2 or auto...`